# How to pick up specific lines from text file in c#?

Tags: c#

I Have the file as shown below

```
  aaaaaaa
  ID 12345
  David
  bbbbbbbbbbb
```

I have to separate the Id and Name of the person

My output should be like

```
12345
David
```

Could anyone help, please? thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the format of the file documented? Are there multiple pieces of data in the file? What is the significance of `aaaaaa` and `bbbbb`?

Comment: will the name and number having same location each time?

Comment: @Dai yes there are multiple lines in the file, I mentioned aaa and bbb instead of different lines in the file

Comment: @Pavvy Nope, But the  "ID" is constant, I tried with the reference of "ID" but i unable to pick up Name of the person

Comment: Share your code how you tried to fetch Id & name from text file.

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid: That is the question actually

Comment: It's possible only if the Name is coming next to the number each time. Are you sure about it? Else as per my guess there is no such way to find out this text. Regular expression could work to fields like phonenumber, email etc.

Comment: @Pavvy Yes, Name comes only after ID

Comment: will it have more IDs and Names and you need to fetch them all?

Comment: @un-lucky Nope, Just one ID

Comment: Bhargav, how to get these details depends on the structure of the file. In a given file, are your expecting these four lines to repeat multiple times? What separates two such data blocks? Is the separator always going to be a line break?

Comment: @A3006 Those four lines won't repeat in my file, Line Break is the separator and ID is constant remaining lines might change depend up on the file

Comment: In that case, un-lucky's solution will work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following code will help you for this particular problem, try this and let me know if you are facing any difficulties:

```
 var linesInFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Vishnuraj\Desktop\sample.txt").ToList();

 var lineOfID = linesInFile.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToLower().StartsWith("id"));
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lineOfID))
 {
     int indexOfID = linesInFile.IndexOf(lineOfID);
     if (indexOfID < linesInFile.Count - 1)
     {
         string nameOfPerson = linesInFile[indexOfID + 1]; // will be "David"
         string personId = lineOfID.Substring(3); // will be 12345
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @Bhargav: Glad to hear. Happy to help you..........

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch your id and name like this:

```
        string[]file= File.ReadAllLines(filePath); //Read your text file this way.
        int id = 1; //first id will be found at index 1 as mentioned by you.
        for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == id)
            {
                //here is your id & Name
                Console.WriteLine(file[i]);
                if (file[id + 1] != null)//checking whether next index if null or not.
                    Console.WriteLine(file[id + 1]);
                id += 4;//incremented as you said, it always be there in a sequence
            }
        }
```

You can further refine this code like convert the array to a `List` and apply `LINQ` etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you NuGet "System.Interactive" then you can do this:

```
var lines = 
    File
        .ReadLines(fileName)
        .Skip(1)
        .Take(2)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Split(' ').TakeLast(1))
        .ToArray();

var id = lines[0];
var name = lines[1];
```